# Marshalling a System.IO.Stream object in c# COM interface

Tags: c#, stream, com, c++-cli, marshalling

I have a function in my c# COM interface which returns a System.IO.Stream object:

```
Stream GetFile();
```

I intend to use this COM interface within unmanaged c++ code, and call this function from there, but by default the "Stream" object is just marshalled as an undefined struct.

Based on what I have read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshalling).  It seems like I would need to implement my own "Stream" class within the COM interface and use that class on the c++ end, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.  I was hoping I could just marshal the stream as a byte array so that I can just return a SAFEARRAY on the c++ end, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Is there a way to marshal the stream object returned from this function as a byte array so that, if this function is called in unmanaged c++, it just returns a byte array instead of a stream?  Or is there another way to marshal a stream object so that I can call this function from unmanaged code?

Comment: if you want it to return a byte array why not make it so the function returns a byte array?

Comment: My understanding is that streams are more robust/versatile than byte arrays, so I would like to keep the library this way in case it is called in other environments other than unmanaged c++.  The only time I would want to use a byte array would be in this case.  That is assuming there isn't a adequate counterpart to the System.IO.Stream object I can use in unmanaged c++ instead.

Comment: So you don't want to marshal a stream as a stream class... because it's too much work, and you'd rather have a byte array instead... but if called from some other environment... you want to return a stream class... which requires marshalling?

Comment: @user253751 I had thought that the only (or at least the majority of the) time we would need to marshal this stream object would be when going to unmanaged code, which is why I only considered marshalling in that scenario.  If I were to re-implement the System.IO.Stream class, would I need to implement it in it's entirety?

Comment: COM interfaces are COM interfaces, they have to work with COM. No? I'm not too familiar with C# but I do know that COM interfaces are the same interfaces in every language

Comment: COM does have a stream interface (IStream) and I'm surprised if C# doesn't have something built-in compatible with it.

Comment: The marshaller cannot magically transform any arbitrary .Net object into a COM objects. If you want to use COM for interop you need to follow the rules of COM with interfaces and such. Personally I would just turn on clr support in my c++ project and skip the whole COM-part, if that is an option at all. That way you *can* use arbitrary .Net objects in your c++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) which is a fairly well-known Windows (COM) type and implement it with C# (both ways from native to .NET and from .NET to native), for example like this:

```
public sealed class ManagedIStream : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;

    public ManagedIStream(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
    }

    public void Read(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbRead)
    {
        if (pv == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pv));

        var read = _stream.Read(pv, 0, cb);
        if (pcbRead != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbRead, read);
        }
    }

    public void Write(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbWritten)
    {
        if (pv == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pv));

        _stream.Write(pv, 0, cb);
        if (pcbWritten != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbWritten, cb);
        }
    }

    public void Seek(long dlibMove, int dwOrigin, IntPtr plibNewPosition)
    {
        var newPos = _stream.Seek(dlibMove, (SeekOrigin)dwOrigin);
        if (plibNewPosition != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.WriteInt64(plibNewPosition, newPos);
        }
    }

    public void SetSize(long libNewSize) => _stream.SetLength(libNewSize);
    public void Commit(int grfCommitFlags) => _stream.Flush();

    public void Stat(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG pstatstg, int grfStatFlag)
    {
        pstatstg = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG
        {
            type = (int)STGTY.STGTY_STREAM,
            cbSize = _stream.Length,
            grfMode = 0
        };

        if (_stream.CanRead && _stream.CanWrite)
        {
            pstatstg.grfMode |= (int)STGM.STGM_READWRITE;
            return;
        }

        if (_stream.CanRead)
        {
            pstatstg.grfMode |= (int)STGM.STGM_READ;
            return;
        }

        if (_stream.CanWrite)
        {
            pstatstg.grfMode |= (int)STGM.STGM_WRITE;
            return;
        }

        throw new IOException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream pstm, long cb, IntPtr pcbRead, IntPtr pcbWritten)
    {
        if (pstm == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pstm));

        long count;
        using (var stream = new StreamOnIStream(pstm))
        {
            count = CopyTo(_stream, stream, cb);
        }

        if (pcbRead != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbRead, count);
        }

        if (pcbWritten != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbWritten, count);
        }
    }

    private static long CopyTo(Stream input, Stream output, long count = long.MaxValue, int bufferSize = 0x14000)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

        if (count <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(count));

        if (bufferSize <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(bufferSize));

        if (count < bufferSize)
        {
            bufferSize = (int)count;
        }

        var bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var max = (int)Math.Min(count - total, bytes.Length);
            var read = input.Read(bytes, 0, max);
            if (read == 0)
                break;

            output.Write(bytes, 0, read);
            total += read;
            if (total == count)
                break;
        }
        while (true);
        return total;
    }

    public void Revert() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public void LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public void UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public void Clone(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream ppstm) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

public class StreamOnIStream : Stream
{
    private const int STATFLAG_NONAME = 1;

    private System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream _stream;
    private IntPtr _ptr;
    private long _position;

    public StreamOnIStream(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf<long>()); // works for 32b & 64b
        CanRead = true;
        CanSeek = true;
        CanWrite = true;
    }

    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream NativeStream => CheckDisposed();
    public override bool CanTimeout => false;
    public override int ReadTimeout => Timeout.Infinite;
    public override int WriteTimeout => Timeout.Infinite;
    public override bool CanRead { get; }
    public override bool CanSeek { get; }
    public override bool CanWrite { get; }
    public override long Position { get => _position; set => Seek(value, SeekOrigin.Begin); }
    public override long Length { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return stat.cbSize; } }
    public DateTimeOffset CreationTime { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return ToDateTimeOffset(stat.ctime); } }
    public DateTimeOffset LastWriteTime { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return ToDateTimeOffset(stat.mtime); } }
    public DateTimeOffset LastAccessTime { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return ToDateTimeOffset(stat.atime); } }
    public Guid Clsid { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return stat.clsid; } }
    public string Name { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, 0); return stat.pwcsName; } }
    public STGM StorageMode { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return (STGM)stat.grfMode; } }
    public STGTY StorageType { get { CheckDisposed().Stat(out var stat, STATFLAG_NONAME); return (STGTY)stat.type; } }

    private static DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME fileTime)
    {
        var ft = (((long)fileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + fileTime.dwLowDateTime;
        return DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime(ft);
    }

    public virtual void Flush(STGC options) => CheckDisposed().Commit((int)options);
    public override void Flush() => Flush(STGC.STGC_DEFAULT);

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buffer));

        if (offset < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));

        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));

        if (count == 0)
            return 0;

        if (offset == 0)
            return Read(buffer, count);

        var bytes = new byte[count];
        var read = Read(bytes, bytes.Length);
        if (read > 0)
        {
            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, buffer, offset, read);
        }
        return read;
    }

    private int Read(byte[] buffer, int count)
    {
        CheckDisposed().Read(buffer, count, _ptr);
        var read = Marshal.ReadInt32(_ptr);
        _position += read;
        return read;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value) => CheckDisposed().SetSize(value);
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        CheckDisposed().Seek(offset, (int)origin, _ptr);
        _position = Marshal.ReadInt64(_ptr);
        return _position;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buffer));

        if (offset < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));

        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));

        if (count == 0)
            return;

        if (offset == 0)
        {
            CheckDisposed().Write(buffer, count, _ptr);
        }
        else
        {
            var bytes = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, bytes, 0, count);
            CheckDisposed().Write(bytes, bytes.Length, _ptr);
        }

        var written = Marshal.ReadInt32(_ptr);
        _position += written;
    }

    private System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream CheckDisposed()
    {
        var stream = _stream;
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(NativeStream));

        return stream;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        var stream = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _stream, null);
        if (stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.Commit((int)STGC.STGC_DEFAULT);
            }
#pragma warning disable CA1031 // Do not catch general exception types
            catch
            {
                //+ do nothing
            }
#pragma warning restore CA1031 // Do not catch general exception types
        }

        var ptr = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _ptr, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
        }
    }
}

[Flags]
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Naming", "CA1712:Do not prefix enum values with type name")]
public enum STGC
{
    STGC_DEFAULT = 0x0,
    STGC_OVERWRITE = 0x1,
    STGC_ONLYIFCURRENT = 0x2,
    STGC_DANGEROUSLYCOMMITMERELYTODISKCACHE = 0x4,
    STGC_CONSOLIDATE = 0x8
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Naming", "CA1712:Do not prefix enum values with type name")]
[Flags]
public enum STGM
{
    STGM_DIRECT = 0x00000000,
    STGM_TRANSACTED = 0x00010000,
    STGM_SIMPLE = 0x08000000,
    STGM_READ = 0x00000000,
    STGM_WRITE = 0x00000001,
    STGM_READWRITE = 0x00000002,
    STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE = 0x00000040,
    STGM_SHARE_DENY_READ = 0x00000030,
    STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE = 0x00000020,
    STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000010,
    STGM_PRIORITY = 0x00040000,
    STGM_DELETEONRELEASE = 0x04000000,
    STGM_NOSCRATCH = 0x00100000,
    STGM_CREATE = 0x00001000,
    STGM_CONVERT = 0x00020000,
    STGM_FAILIFTHERE = 0x00000000,
    STGM_NOSNAPSHOT = 0x00200000,
    STGM_DIRECT_SWMR = 0x00400000,
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Naming", "CA1712:Do not prefix enum values with type name")]
public enum STGTY
{
    STGTY_STORAGE = 1,
    STGTY_STREAM = 2,
    STGTY_LOCKBYTES = 3,
    STGTY_PROPERTY = 4,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I just want to confirm I understand how these classes you provided would be used.  Would my methods in my COM interface now use `ManagedIStream` objects instead of the original `System.IO.Stream` objects as arguments?  And instead of using `System.IO.Stream` functions in my COM implementation, I would use functions of the `StreamOnIStream` class?

Comment: @naota29 - It depends how your code is designed. What it means is you can pass to or use an IStream from native code, so you'll use streaming-style coding (instead of byte array, safe array, etc.). For example you can declare a c# static dll import like this: `private static int Save(IStream strm)` and implement it in C/C++